# Electron Desktop app to upload Video to Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, xmlhttprequest, electron

Hi I need help with implementing a very simple Electron App, which has a very basic input form
for title, description and select file.

Then a user selects upload and it should upload the small video (35 mb) into my fb page.

I've tried using the FB api SDK, but it's not clear how you set it up.  I even tried the unofficial npm package facebook-api-video-upload and that didn't work at all.

Now, I've been successful with executing a cURL call on terminal and having the video upload perfectly,

It looked something like this:

cURL -X POST "https://graph-video.facebook.com/....." -F "access_token=...." -F "....=@video.mp4"

So I tried executing this command via my electron app, and the only method that got a response was executing via a XMLHttpRequest().  But the problem is, the response my app gets is that the video is too large??  I've even tried uploading the same exact video.

Btw I wish to do this via JS/electron on desktop, don't want to set up server and use FB php's script.

Any help much appreciated.

```
(anonymous) @ mainWindow.html:239
mainWindow.html:236 {
   "error": {
      "message": "There was a problem uploading your video file. Please try again.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 390,
      "error_subcode": 1363030,
      "is_transient": true,
      "error_user_title": "Video Upload Time Out",
      "error_user_msg": "Your video upload timed out before it could be completed. This is probably because of a slow network connection or because the video you're trying to upload is too large. Please try again.",
      "fbtrace_id": "..."
   }
}
```

Comment: _Other_ users are supposed to upload a video to your page here? You are not talking about the page admin, but just any arbitrary user of your app? That would mean you would need to expose your page access token in client-side code then, I guess? That is an absolute NO GO to begin with. In that case you have to do it from the server side, so that your token does not get exposed to people who have no business knowing it in the first place.

Comment: No it'll be an in-house software, my assistants in the media team will be using it.

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre] then. You have not even shown us any relevant code yet - so impossible for anyone to tell, if it is due to a mistake you made with that, or something else.

Comment: The electron app I made is very messy, since I tried more that 5 different js packages.  At this point, just want to know what's the best way to execute the equivalent of cURL post on terminal in Electron desktop app.